# VBA Access subform gets unbound after editing data in one row and then clicking another row

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, stored-procedures, ms-access-2007, ado

For a client I have to use MS Access 2007 as a lightweight front-end to SQL Server 2008.
One of the requirements, security-wise, is that I need to fetch my recordset data via stored procedures. I'm doing this via SQLOLEDB, based on tutorials provided here: http://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/07/29/sql-server-stored-procedure-guide-for-microsoft-access-part-1/

I have a mainform with some general data, on which I also set the form recordset (Me.recordset) in the code-behind. At the bottom of the form, there is a subform, with a table of rows of data. This is also an ADO recordset being set in the code. In order to make those subform records editable, I made a extra recordset in which I cloned the data in, then I bound it to the subform's recordset (Me.recordset -> but in context subform). I added a save button after each row in the subform, and via an event I'm doing the writes manually via another stored procedure.

This all works, but I get some very weird behavior when I edit some data in the first row (for example), and then click on a field in another row (for example the second row). Now suddenly all my fields change to '#Name?'; basically my subform gets unbound.

Now I'm not sure how to debug this, let stand fix it. Any help on this error is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to put tempRs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

It is working as intended now :)